# Grep exclude count of occurence match between comments <!-- --> of curl body

Tags: regex, bash, curl, awk, grep

I am very new to linux & bash script. I'm trying to read an xml file using curl command and count the number of occurrence of the word `</entity>` in it.

`curl -s "https://server:port/app/collection/admin/file?wt=xml&_=12334343432&file=samplefile.xml&contentType=text%2Fxml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8" | grep '</entity>'  -oP | wc -l`

This works correctly, however the xml file consists of comments like below resulting in wrong count.

Sample XML file

```
.........
........
 <entity>
.......
.......
</entity>
........
........
<!--
.......
<entity>
........
</entity>
.......
.......
-->
<entity>
.......
........
</entity>
```

The expected output should be 2 since one of the match is inside the comment block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `gnu-grep` here is a PCRE regex solution for your problem:

```sh
curl -s "https://server:port/app/collection/admin/file?wt=xml&_=12334343432&file=samplefile.xml&contentType=text%2Fxml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8" |
grep -ZzoP '(?s)<!--.*?-->(*SKIP)(*F)|</entity>' |
tr '\0' '\n' |
wc -l

2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uoM0Pd/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?s)`: Enable DOTALL mode so that dot matches line breaks also
- `<!--.*?-->`: Match a commented block
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: skips and fails this commented block
- `|`: OR
- `</entity>`: Match `</entity>` outside commented block
- `tr '\0' '\n'`: Converts NUL bytes to line break
- `wc -l`: Counts number of lines

Answer (score 3):

As usual when dealing with XML, regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job. Use something aware of the format. For example, using `xmllint` and some XPath:

```sh
curl ... | xmllint --xpath 'count(//entity)' -
```

(Note the trailing `-`; unlike many programs, `xmllint` won't automatically read from standard input if not given a filename on the command line)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
your_curl_command | 
awk -v RS="" '
match($0,/(^|\n)<!--[^-]*-->/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(val,"")
}
END{
  while(match($0,/(\n|^)[[:space:]]*<entity>[^<]*<\/entity>/)){
    count++
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  print count
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
your_curl_command |                ##Running curl command and sending its output to awk command.
awk -v RS="" '                     ##Setting RS as NULL for this awk program.
match($0,/(^|\n)<!--[^-]*-->/){    ##Using match function of awk where using regex (^|\n)<!--[^-]*-->(explained below)
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##if match of regex is found then assigning sub string value of matched value to val here.
  gsub(val,"")                     ##Using gsub(Global substitution) function to substitute globally val with NULL in current line in whole line.
}
END{                               ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  while(match($0,/(\n|^)[[:space:]]*<entity>[^<]*<\/entity>/)){  ##Using while loop to match regex (\n|^)[[:space:]]*<entity>[^<]*<\/entity> in match function to get all the matches to get count.
    count++                        ##Adding 1 to count variable here.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)   ##Assigning rest of line value to current line to avoid previous match.
  }
  print count                      ##Printing count value here.
}
'
```

***Explanation of 1st regex(`(^|\n)<!--[^-]*-->`):***

```
(^|\n)    ##Matching either starting of value OR new line here.
<!--[^-]* ##Followed by <!-- till next value of - here.
-->       ##Followed by --> here.
```

***Explanation of 2nd regex(`(\n|^)[[:space:]]*<entity>[^<]*<\/entity>`):***

```
(\n|^)                ##Matching new line OR starting of value.
[[:space:]]*<entity>  ##Followed by spaces(0 or more occurrence) followed by <entity>
[^<]*                 ##Followed by matching just before <
<\/entity>            ##Followed by </entity> here.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2/nawk '
BEGIN {
 1      FS = RS = "^$"
 1      _____ = "[<][\\/]entity[>]"
 1      ____ = "\23\4"
 1      ___ =   "\32"
 1      __ = ("[\\n][<][!]")(_="[-][-][\\n]")
 1      sub("......","[\\n]&[>]",_)
}

# Rule(s)

 1  ($!-_=gsub(_____,"&",
     $((  gsub(__,____)*gsub(_, ___)*\
          gsub(____"[^"(___)"]*"___,""))~"")))_'
```

---

```
2
```